# Object Initialization - Java

Tags: java, class, oop, object, instance

I am new to Java.

I want to ask about object initialization. First, I make a class.

```
public class A {

    ....

}
```

Then at the main class, the A class is instantiated.

```
A a = new A();
```

Now, the question is, whether these two codes are the same?

```
A aa = a;
```

and

```
A aa = new A();
```

Comment: Not the same - in first case - two references point to the same object, in the second case, two separate A objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they are totally different!

```
A aa = a;
```

Then `aa` and `a` refert to the same object in memory.

```
A aa = new A();
```

Then aa is a new object. And you have now two objects on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

```
A aa = a
```

will make a reference to object a, however

```
A aa = new A();
```

will make a new object of type A.

Answer (score 0):

```
A a = new A();
A aa = a;
```

aa refers to the same object a.

```
A aa = new A();
```

about statement created new object of type A which is different from the a.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are different.
While `A aa = new A();` creates a new Object of type A,
`A aa = a;` just passes the reference of `a` to `aa`, which means, those two point to the same Object.
You can verify this by printing the hashcode of `a` and `aa`.

In the first case `A aa = a;` calling `hashCode()` on both `aa` and `a` will yield the same result, since both point to the same Object.

In your second case `A aa = new A();` calling `hashCode()` will yield different results, since you're creating a whole new instance of `A`.